# Почему появляется полоса прокрутки

Tags: html, jquery, css

Вроде бы прописал `overflow: hidden`, но работает только если прописать к `body`

```js
$(".buttonTransition").on('click',function () {
   $(".header-bg").animate({left: '-100vw'},2500);
   setTimeout(function () {
      $(".header-bg").css({
          'display': 'none'
      })
   },2500);
   setTimeout(function () {
       $(".test").css('display','block').animate({right:'30vw'},3000);

   });
   
});
```

```css
body, h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0; }

header {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; }

.header-bg {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden; }
  .header-bg .top-header {
    text-align: center; }
    .header-bg .top-header .upper-phrase {
      color: #9d7722;
      padding-top: 40px; }
    .header-bg .top-header h2 {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 40px;
      letter-spacing: 7px;
      padding-top: 20px; }
  .header-bg .center-header {
    width: 40%;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto; }
    .header-bg .center-header h1 {
      color: #ffffff;
      max-font-size: 100%;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
      padding-top: 25px;
      font-stretch: ultra-expanded; }
    .header-bg .center-header h2 {
      color: #f4b325;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 55px;
      letter-spacing: 10px; }
    .header-bg .center-header img {
      border-radius: 10px;
      max-width: 100%; }

.buttonTransition {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 98%;
  transform: translate(-98%, -50%);
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #d3c7b7; }

.test {
  display: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
  right: -45vw; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <section class="test">
        <h1>sadgoogsdaog</h1>
    </section>
    <div class="header-bg">
        <div class="top-header">
            <h1 CLASS="upper-phrase">Best Quality</h1>
            <h2>THE</h2>
            <div class="center-header">
                    <h1>BURGER</h1>
               
                    <h2>HOUSE</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonTransition">
            <h3>goo!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/fbea3x8j/

Comment: Странно,вроде указал)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При выполении анимации `header` додает ещо и `.test` который у вас `-45vw` я немного изменил код с добавлением класса `active`

```js
$(".buttonTransition").on('click',function () {
   $(".header-bg").animate({left: '-100vw'},2500);
   $(".test").addClass('active');
   setTimeout(function () {
      $(".header-bg").css({
          'display': 'none'
      })
   },2500);
   setTimeout(function () {
       $(".test").animate({right:'30vw'},3000);

   });
   
});
```

```css
body, h1 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  }
header {
  background-color: #1c1c1c;
height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden; }

.header-bg {
  position: relative;
  height:100vh;}
  .header-bg .top-header {
    text-align: center; }
    .header-bg .top-header .upper-phrase {
      color: #9d7722;
      padding-top: 40px; }
    .header-bg .top-header h2 {
      color: #ffffff;
      font-size: 40px;
      letter-spacing: 7px;
      padding-top: 20px; }
  .header-bg .center-header {
    width: 40%;
    border-top: 2px solid black;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    }
    .header-bg .center-header h1 {
      color: #ffffff;
      max-font-size: 100%;
      letter-spacing: 10px;
      padding-top: 25px;
      font-stretch: ultra-expanded; }
    .header-bg .center-header h2 {
      color: #f4b325;
      margin: 0;
      font-size: 55px;
      letter-spacing: 10px; }
    .header-bg .center-header img {
      border-radius: 10px;
      max-width: 100%; }

.buttonTransition {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 98%;
  transform: translate(-98%, -50%);
  border: 3px solid black;
  text-align: center;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #d3c7b7; }

.test {
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0vw; 
  display:block;}
.test.active{
opacity:1;
transition:opacity 0.5s linear 1.3s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
    <section class="test">
        <h1>sadgoogsdaog</h1>
    </section>
    <div class="header-bg">
        <div class="top-header">
            <h1 CLASS="upper-phrase">Best Quality</h1>
            <h2>THE</h2>
            <div class="center-header">
                    <h1>BURGER</h1>
               
                    <h2>HOUSE</h2>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttonTransition">
            <h3>goo!</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```